# how to set a wiki like application only for known users or know IP?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there any way to set the access to a wiki like application only for some known users and known IP adress.

my requirement is, I want to store/share some of the my project installation details and setting to my colleague. But don't want to show it to the public.

what i need is mediaWiki like application. 
but the login and access are restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's no problem.

My very favorite wiki, [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki), is really simple to install and it will let you restrict access based on username/password pairs, and if I was to add IP-based filtering, I would do that though Apache.

A bit more: I like DokuWiki because the install is so, so simple (untar it and you're done), it's targeted towards programmers and it's got just about every feature I want.  It's one of the few applications that makes me happy every time I go to use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Apache:  http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-htaccess.html

That explains everything you will ever want to know on htaccess files and how to restrict access to users via IP.

Works for any wiki/blog/whatever you will want to run.

One caveat may be that your users are not using static IPs. I'd find that out before you commit yourself to restricting via IP.

Answer (score 1):

Media Wiki allows for blocking of everyone except specific IPs. You might want to try that.

Comment: You can also set mediawiki so content pages can only be seen by logged in users.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the IP address, since it's likely to change for a given client.  If the security constraints are relatively relaxed, try using an authentication cookie, or some forms based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set this up on your web server, enable IP Address Restrictions (IIS) or mod_access module in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all wiki software I've ever used or installed has had the ability to limit viewing to known users (e.g. a private wiki).

At work, we use Screwturn Wiki which has a 'Private Mode' in which a user needs to be signed in to use it. Of course, there's also server-side settings to limit access to known IP addresses as well.